# Use Jquery animate to have a button move a box to the next corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am new to using javascript and jquery so I'm having some problems figuring this one out.

I am trying to use the animate function in jquery to move a box from one corner to the next.

- The box begins on the top-left corner of the screen and upon clicking the 'go' button, it will move to the next corner (top-right).
- Clicking the same 'go' button then moves the box to the next corner (bottom-right).
- Clicking the 'go' button once more will move it to the next corner (bottom-left).
- Clicking the 'go' button once more will move it to the next corner (top-left, which is the start).

I've included a picture to show exactly what I mean by this:
[*What the program should do!*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlVq9.png)

So, this is what I've got so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#go').click(function(){
  var dest = parseInt($('#block').css('margin-left').replace('px', '')) + 100;
   if (dest > 0) {
    $('#block').animate({
    marginLeft: '1800px'
      }, 0 );
     }
   else {
    $('#block').animate({
    marginLeft: dest + 'px'
    }, 0 );
   }
  });
});
```

```css
#block {
        width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: red; 
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
 <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
```

I've got the box to move to the top-right corner but cannot figure out how to make it now move down using the same button. 
I've tried something with a toggle but it did not work. That looked something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#go').click(function(){
    var toggle = 1
        if (toggle == 1){
            $("#block").animate({left: "80px"});
            toggle = 0;
        } else{
            $("#block").animate({right: "80px"});
            toggle = 1;
        }
    });
```

I was thinking of maybe [*using cases to switch*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) between which coordinates the button will move the box to. However, I have no knowledge of how this works with jquery and the animate function.

If anyone has any other ideas or knows how to use the case switches in this scenario, I would really appreciate it and thank you in advance!

P.S. I've tried searching this answer on here for a couple of hours now and have not found much that will help me. I am hoping this question will serve to help others who are having a similar problem to mine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var leftValue = window.innerWidth - 115; // 115 is a temp value
  var topValue = window.innerHeight - 115;
  var actionNum = 0;
  var movingBlock = $('#block');
  
  $('#go').click(function () {
    if (actionNum < 4) {
      actionNum++;    
    } else {
      actionNum = 1;
    }
    
    switch (actionNum) {
      case 1:
       // move to the top right
        movingBlock.animate({
          left: leftValue + 'px',
          top: 0
        }, 1000);
       break;
      case 2:
       // move to the bottom right
        movingBlock.animate({
          left: leftValue + 'px',
          top: topValue + 'px'
        }, 1000);
        break;
      case 3:
       // move to the left bottom
       movingBlock.animate({
         top: topValue + 'px',
         left: 0
       }, 1000);
       break;
      case 4:
       // move to the top left
        movingBlock.animate({
          left: 0,
          top: 0
        }, 1000);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: red; 
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#go {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked well and I notice my biggest error now. I was trying to switch cases without using 'actionNum' so it had no way of changing which case it was currently on.

Comment: @CorpRocket, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a multi solution for your problem ,

So I suggest some simple solution , is that you pput position absolute to your div ,

then change (annimate) the left or top of this last after checking conditions ,

you can get top left position in Jquery using [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) funcion ,

See belwon Snippet (added , 1000 milisseconde in order to show annimation transition )

```js
var widh_annimation = "400px";
var hieght_annimation = "100px";

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#go').click(function(){
    var position = $("#block").position();
      var annimation = {};
      if(position.left == 0 && position.top == 0) {
        annimation = { left:widh_annimation};
      }else if(position.left > 0 && position.top == 0) {
        annimation = { top:hieght_annimation};
      }else if(position.left > 0 && position.top > 0) {
        annimation = { left:"0"};
      }else if(position.left == 0 && position.top > 0) {
        annimation = { top:"0"};
      }      
      $('#block').animate(annimation, 1000 );
  });
});
```

```css
#block {
        width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background: red; 
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
    position:absolute;
}

#go {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
 <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
```